# How to add ToolBar in PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, toolbar, preferenceactivity

I want to add `ToolBar` in `PreferenceActivity` in my android application. I wrote the following code.

```
  public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity  {
 SendSMS sms;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar bar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.action_bar_setting, root, false);
    root.addView(bar, 0);
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

}

This worked perfectly in my android **Kitkat** phone API 19 but force closed in API level 10 i.e. **gingerbread**. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 35):

You need a layout that contains a `Toolbar`, and a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"`

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/content_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
    ...
}
```

Check out my fully working example:

- [activity_settings.xml](https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_settings.xml)
- [SettingsActivity.java](https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/hidroh/materialistic/SettingsActivity.java)

Reference from the Android team: [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java)

Comment: Hidro, why the layout needs a ListView?

Comment: Work for me after add the ListView in layout, but the action bar was below the layout.

Comment: `PreferenceActivity` requires a `ListView` with `android:id/list` in the layout if you override the layout, that's why.

Comment: Now I could make it work. Thank you, @hidro, for your explanation.

Comment: doesn't work for me... It does shows the toolbar but its under the preference layout.

Comment: On Android 4.4 I'm loosing paddings from the list, so the activity doesn't look like native.

Comment: there is no setSupportActionBar method on PreferenceActivity

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
.....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    /* getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new GeneralPreferenceFragment())
            .commit();
    */

    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);        
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_root); //id from appcompat

    if (rootView != null) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_bar_layout, rootView, false);
        rootView.addView(view, 0);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**app_bar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: What is AppCompatPreferenceActivity ?

Comment: @Eslam, it's a Class that extends Preference Activity. 'New' -> 'Settings Activity' will make it show up.

Comment: What do you have in `@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` and `@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay` files?

Answer (score 4):

I'm late but here's a small fix to the problem instead of writing tons of code or adding bulky libraries.

Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and to your Preference Activity add the custom `theme`

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard.PreferencepActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_preference"
        android:theme="@style/Pref"></activity>
```

Here's the custom theme added to the above `@style/Pref`

```
 <style name="Pref" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add toolbar from `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`

In **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
    android:label="Settings"/>
```

In **v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

In **v14/styles.xml** for Back API support

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.V14.Movie.NoTitle</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Very easy and working well in my case by inflating custom toolbar.
 In your java code do as below,

```
   public class SettingsPrefActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
        //  private static final String TAG = SettingsPrefActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //setting up toolbar
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_setting, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content));
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
            setSupportActionBars(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // load settings fragment
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
```

and at your xml side code,add one preference category at the top do as below,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
//put below line at the top of your xml preference layout screen..
    <PreferenceCategory android:layout="@layout/toolbar_setting"></PreferenceCategory>
```

and in your layout resource folder toolbar_setting,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/appbar_elevation"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will not solve adding toolbar, but you can get the default `ActionBar` back for your settings page. Create a theme for settings activity, by inheriting from parent theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Settings" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml set the `android:theme`

```
<activity
    android:name=".Settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Settings" />
```

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity
```

Do this:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```