# Android PreferencesActivity and custom Header

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a standard PreferencesActivity declared in the following way:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
   ...
}
```

Then inside the activity I load my Fragment in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .replace(android.R.id.content, new GraphicsFragment())
       .commit();
}
```

And this is my Fragment:

```
public static class GraphicsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.warrior_preference);
    }
}
```

Right now the Activity is completely covered by this Fragment, but what I need is to have an ImageView on top and then the Fragment activity loaded within a ScrollView or something similar. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below.
Create `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/some image" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `PreferencesActivity onCreate` method use below
        write

```
    Fragment newFragment = new GraphicsFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment).commit();;
```

Inside `ImageView` give your `drawable` image.
Please go through below urls for `PreferencesActivity` creation.

[What to use instead of “addPreferencesFromResource” in a PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity)

[How do you create Preference Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523806/how-do-you-create-preference-activity-and-preference-fragment-on-android)

Comment: It doesn't work. I get this error
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.PreferencesActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Not working still same error
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

This is a PreferencesActivity and not a standard activity

Comment: @Raffaeu, I have update my answer and also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647831/android-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-li or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list

Comment: I'll have a look at this

Comment: This is the correct answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139548/how-to-add-toolbar-in-preferenceactivity
Preferences activity needs a listview to hold the preferences fragment and not a fragment or frame layout

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You need to place the fragment inside a specified view in the parent view.

You can also place the fragment directly into your XML file, if it is not necessary to inflate the fragment programmaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you're trying to achieve is completely possible. What can be done to achieve this is applying an imageView and a frameLayout in a layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.android.empty.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@drawable/c1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now change, changing the id of inside the replace method from android.R.id.content to R.id.frame will do the trick.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, new GraphicsFragment())
            .commit();

    //Do what ever you want to with imageview.
```

Actually, android.R.id.content gives the root view in return so the fragment completely covers the layout.