# Make toolbar text color white and prevent overlapp

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to include a toolbar in my settings page and followed this instruction:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455330/2977288 (first part)

For some reason, the toolbar overlaps the content:
[image]

I also tried to make the text color white:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555178/2977288

But as you can see in the screenshot, the color remains black.

Here is the code I'm using:

`settings_toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

`SettingsActivity.java`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
        bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

`preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_main">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="vibration"
            android:title="@string/pref_vibration"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_vibration"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <Preference
            android:key="show_wizard"
            android:title="@string/pref_wizard"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_wizard">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="de.tum.dstrctrl"
                android:targetClass="de.tum.dstrctrl.activities.WizardActivity" />
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Does anybody has an idea about one of the two issues (or both)?

Comment: Please show your `xml ` which contains the `toolbar`.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed it's the first xsml file (settings_toolbar.xml)

Comment: You are including this `settings_toolbar` layout in another `xml` as well. Please show that xml

Comment: It's loaded in the SettingsActivity.java and not in another xml file. Just like in the linked stack answer

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969424/how-to-set-toolbar-text-and-back-arrow-color to change color

Answer (score 1):

Please use the custom layout for the `PreferenceActivity` and in that layout include the `toolbar` and other stuff as suggested on [How to add ToolBar in PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139548/how-to-add-toolbar-in-preferenceactivity).

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
You can change the title color of Toolbar by creating custom style and then use that custom layout in toolbar

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_text</item>
    </style>
```

**settings_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    style="@style/ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Why does it not work with this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27455330/2977288

Comment: What's the purpose of `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();` in `PreferenceActivity`, you have to add the line in `onCreate` as `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`

Comment: I now solved it by using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity instead of fragments. So at least what you said... Any idea about the color?

Comment: That's the thing I just shared that you don't have to use fragment. I tested your code at my end, Just removed the fragment thing and add the line `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` it worked perfectly. No need of fragment

Comment: I just used the fragments, because Android Doc recommends it. Any idea about the text color? It's still balck

Comment: Create the custom `PreferenceCategory` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607302/how-to-change-text-color-of-preference-category-in-android

Comment: It's not the color of the category, but of the text on the toolbar. I followed this instructions, but still does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555178/2977288

Comment: Do you want to change the settings color?

Comment: Yes the color of the word "Settings" and of the arrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101678/discussion-between-mustansar-saeed-and-zoker).